# Using a Javascript DOM Parser extract the list of Layers from the XML response.data of an WMS GetCapabilities request

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, dom, wms

I am trying to extract the list of the names of available layers of a WMS server. I have done so for the GeoMet WMS by sending a GetCapabilities which returns a "application/xml" object that then I parse using a DOM parser. My problem is the Layer tags are nested on two levels. Basically the top level layer contains multiple children layers. How would I extract only the children or list of the parent Layers. I managed to hack together this by realising the children had an attribute that the parent Node did not, but there has to be a better way.

EDIT : I am interested in getting the full list of layers that can be added to an interactive map. Basically all Layer tags that do not have Layer children.

```
axios.get('https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?lang=en&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities').then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.headers)
        const parser = new DOMParser()
        const dom = parser.parseFromString(response.data, 'application/xml')
        let layerGroups = dom.querySelectorAll('[cascaded="0"]')
        let layerNames = []
        layerGroups.forEach(function (domel) { layerNames.push(domel.getElementsByTagName('Name')[0].innerHTML) })
        console.log(layerNames.length)
        this.mylayerlist = layerNames
      })
```

Comment: you could simplify it by using `querySelectorAll('[cascaded="0"] name').map(node => node.innerHTML)`

Comment: Your question isn't clear - are you interested in names like `CGSL.ETA_ICEC
SEA_ICECONC-LINEAR, 
SEA_ICECONC, 
CGSL.ETA_ICEPRS` etc. (there are 12,470 of these...) or something else?

Comment: @PhilipRollins thank you for your time however this is just a hack unfortunately because not all WMS have that attribute associated with the Layer tag. Ideally I would get all the Layer nodes that do not have Layer children this way no matter which WMS I query I would get the full list of layers that can be added to the map.

Comment: @JackFleeting thank you for your time and sorry for the incomplete question. I meant to say that I want all the layers of any Given WMS or in other words if I pass in an URL I get the full list of Layer nodes that do not have Layer children. Yes CGSL.ETA_ICEC and the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this, especially the namespaces. Here's one of them. After your dom declaration try this:

```
xpath = '//*[local-name()="Layer"][@cascaded="0"][not(.//*[local-name()="Layer"])]/*[local-name()="Name"]';
var targets = dom.evaluate(xpath, dom, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
let nodes = Array.from({ length: targets.snapshotLength }, (_, index) => 
console.log(targets.snapshotItem(index).innerHTML));
```

Output is 3,519 (in this case) of names:

```
CGSL.ETA_ICEC
CGSL.ETA_ICEPRS
CGSL.ETA_ICESTG
CGSL.ETA_ICET
CGSL.ETA_ICETK
```

The critical component here is the xpath expression. It selects all `Layer` nodes which have a `cascaded` attribute with a value of `0` and no `Layer` child nodes. In this particular case, none of the `Layer` nodes which have a `cascaded` attribute (note that all of these attributes have a `0` attribute value) have `Layer` children, so you could dispense with one of the two predicates (either `[@cascaded="0"]` or `[not(./*[local-name()="Layer"])]` and get the same output, though this may not be the case with other files).

Comment: Wow thank you so much Mr. Fleeting. I will read up on XPaths. Just to make sure I understand would I write  //*[local-name()="Layer"][not(.//*[local-name()="Layer"])]/*[local-name()="Name"] will return a list of all Layer or Name nodes that do not have Layer children?

Comment: @YordanRadev Almost: that expression returns a collection of all nodes named `Name` which themselves are children of nodes named `Layer` which themselves do not have any children nodes called `Layer`. This collection is an array-like, not an array. The `Array.from` loop converts the collection to an array, and extracts from each array element (that is, each `Name` node)  the inner html/text string which itself is the actual name of the `Name` node. Sorry about this being so confusing, but it can't be helped....

Comment: Thank you sir. I will look into it and at the end of the day it can't be as bad as regex.

Comment: @YordanRadev This is my personal opinion, but I have to say: NOTHING is as bad as regex...