# Parse WMS XML response and return an object containing key-value pairs

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, saxon

Coming off [Using a Javascript DOM Parser extract the list of Layers from the XML response.data of an WMS GetCapabilities request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67408443/13224380) I am trying to implement an xpath that would take the XML response [example](https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&LANG=en&LAYER=CGSL.ETA_ICEC) and return an object that contains the key-value pairs for the leaf Layer tag including Name, Title, Abstract, Dimension : [Dimension_time, Dimension_reference_time], Style: [Styles Names, Titles and URLs] so for the above link :

```
Name: 'CGSL.ETA_ICEC',
Title: 'CGSL.ETA.ICEC - Fraction de glace',
Abstract: 'Le Système régional de prévision déterministe (SRPD) procède à ...',
Dimension: {
    Dimension_time: '2022-03-09T13:00:00Z/2022-03-11T12:00:00Z/PT1H',
    Dimension_ref_time: '2022-03-08T06:00:00Z/2022-03-09T12:00:00Z/PT6H'
},
Style: [
    {
        Name: 'SEA_ICECONC-LINEAR',
        Title: 'SEA_ICECONC-LINEAR',
        LegendWidth: 82,
        LegendHeight: 155,
        LegendURL: 'https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?lang=fr&version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.1.0&layer=CGSL.ETA_ICEC&format=image/png&STYLE=SEA_ICECONC-LINEAR'
    },
    {
        Name: 'SEA_ICECONC',
        Title: 'SEA_ICECONC',
        LegendWidth: 82,
        LegendHeight: 155,
        LegendURL: 'https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?lang=fr&version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.1.0&layer=CGSL.ETA_ICEC&format=image/png&STYLE=SEA_ICECONC'
    }
]
```

And my application runs in the browser and I have access to SaxonJS but if the native DomParser can do the trick it would remove a dependency for me.

```
axios.get('https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&LANG=en&LAYER=CGSL.ETA_ICEC')
.then((response) => {
const xslt =`XSLT`
const jsonResult = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
transform(
map { 
'source-node' : parse-xml($xml), 
'stylesheet-text' : $xslt, 
'delivery-format' : 'raw' 
}
)?output`,
[],
{ 'params': { 'xml': response.data, 'xslt': xslt }})
console.log(tempObject);
```

---

### EDIT : Thank you Mr. Martin Honnen

Mr. Honnen has the exact solution I was looking for and I think I understand better how SaxonJS works thanks to him. People like him are the backbone of programming and I hope I get to help others like he does one day.

Comment: So you have posted your requirements and your intention to implement them with XPath, but where is your intent to solve that?

Comment: @MartinHonnen by intent do you mean my attempts to solve it sir?

Comment: Yes, sure your intent to use the "native" XPath 1 support to select the data you are looking for or your intent to use Saxon-JS to select it? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an XML input, your current XSLT and the expected output - all reduced to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you for the feedback sir but I have already posted the example XML as the link in my question named "example" and the example output is the first text block. I gave up on trying with Saxon JS because I found a hacky solution using a DomParser as mentioned in the Edit in response to Mr. Honnen's comment. I can show my hacky solution but it will not help me learn or understand the best solution.

Comment: 1. You are supposed to include the code in your question, not in external links. 2. 302 lines of code is not "minimal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath a `Layer` not containg another `Layer` would be selected by `Layer[not(.//Layer)]` (ignoring namespaces, for the time).

With Saxon-JS and XPath 3.1, to have JavaScript objects and arrays on the JavaScript side, you can use XPath 3.1 maps (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps) and arrays (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrays):

```js
const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`doc($url)//Layer[not(.//Layer)]!map {
  'Name' : string(Name),
  'Title' : string(Title),
  'Abstract' : string(Abstract),
  'Dimension' : map {
    'Dimension_time' : string(Dimension[@name = 'time']),
    'Dimension_ref_time' : string(Dimension[@name = 'reference_time'])
  },
  'Style' : array { Style !
    map {
      'Name' : string(Name),
      'Title' : string(Title),
      'LegendWith' : string(LegendURL/@width),
      'LegendHeight' : string(LegendURL/@height),
      'LegendURL' : string(LegendURL/OnlineResource/@xlink:href)
    }
  }
}`, null, { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.opengis.net/wms', namespaceContext : { xlink : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' }, params : { url : 'https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&LANG=en&LAYER=CGSL.ETA_ICEC' } });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```

The only drawback of relying on XPath 3.1 maps is that they are unordered so in the end the result might look like

```
{
  "Abstract": "The Regional Deterministic Prediction System (RDPS) carries out physics calculations to arrive at deterministic predictions of atmospheric elements from the current day out to 84 hours into the future. Atmospheric elements include temperature, precipitation, cloud cover, wind speed and direction, humidity and others. This product contains raw numerical results of these calculations. Geographical coverage includes Canada and the United States. Data is available at horizontal resolution of about 10 km up to 33 vertical levels. Predictions are performed four times a day.",
  "Dimension": {
    "Dimension_time": "2022-03-10T13:00:00Z/2022-03-12T12:00:00Z/PT1H",
    "Dimension_ref_time": "2022-03-09T06:00:00Z/2022-03-10T12:00:00Z/PT6H"
  },
  "Name": "CGSL.ETA_ICEC",
  "Title": "CGSL.ETA.ICEC - Ice cover fraction",
  "Style": [
    {
      "LegendWith": "82",
      "LegendURL": "https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.1.0&layer=CGSL.ETA_ICEC&format=image/png&STYLE=SEA_ICECONC-LINEAR",
      "LegendHeight": "155",
      "Name": "SEA_ICECONC-LINEAR",
      "Title": "SEA_ICECONC-LINEAR"
    },
    {
      "LegendWith": "82",
      "LegendURL": "https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.1.0&layer=CGSL.ETA_ICEC&format=image/png&STYLE=SEA_ICECONC",
      "LegendHeight": "155",
      "Name": "SEA_ICECONC",
      "Title": "SEA_ICECONC"
    }
  ]
}
```

i.e. the objects might have their properties in a different order than in the wanted result.

If you have the XML as a string, as your `response.data`, use `parse-xml` e.g.

```
axios.get('https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&LANG=en&LAYER=CGSL.ETA_ICEC')
.then((response) => {
        const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`parse-xml($xml)//Layer[not(.//Layer)]!map {
      'Name' : string(Name),
      'Title' : string(Title),
      'Abstract' : string(Abstract),
      'Dimension' : map {
        'Dimension_time' : string(Dimension[@name = 'time']),
        'Dimension_ref_time' : string(Dimension[@name = 'reference_time'])
      },
      'Style' : array { Style !
        map {
          'Name' : string(Name),
          'Title' : string(Title),
          'LegendWith' : string(LegendURL/@width),
          'LegendHeight' : string(LegendURL/@height),
          'LegendURL' : string(LegendURL/OnlineResource/@xlink:href)
        }
      }
    }`, null, { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.opengis.net/wms', namespaceContext : { xlink : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' }, params : { xml: response.data } });

      })
```

Comment: You are the best!!! Thank you so much Sir.